# Filter "NULL model" from STL

Tags: r, time-series

Applying STL:
`model(STL(n ~ season(window = "periodic")))`

from library(feasts) to my time-  series  results in some NULL models:
ORTH NULL model.
How can I filter "NULL model" from result to avoid problems with components() ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `is_null_model()` function to identify which models have failed. In combination with `filter()` from the dplyr package, you can remove these with:

```r
data %>%
  model(stl = STL(n ~ season(window = "periodic"))) %>%
  filter(!is_null_model(stl))
```

It is worth considering why your data/model is erroring to see if this issue can be fixed instead.